# Using Vue to redirect to edit resource controllers edit.blade.php get method for editing profile details

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to convert an anchor tag button into a component that contains the /profile/{{$user->id}}/edit path of a laravel application to edit the details of the user profile.

I was wondering if this is possible with vue to dynamically change the path of the URL.

Some test cases we have so far done is testing out using try catch method

[image]

[image]

[image]

We tried setting up a try catch method

I'm currently testing out creating an EditController and then setup a route for it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Vue.js, you can dynamically change the URL path in an anchor tag button. To do this, you need to create a Vue component and utilize Vue's data binding and interpolation features.

First, let's address the issue with the syntax `{{ $user->id }}` in the `.vue` file. This syntax is used in Blade files, not in Vue files. Therefore, the URL in your `EditButton.vue` component won't work and will display the literal URL instead, like the one you mentioned: `127.0.0.1:8000/profile/{{$user->id}}/edit`.

To make it work with Vue, we need to use the correct syntax.

Vue provides a feature called "text interpolation" that allows us to bind data to elements using double curly braces (Mustache syntax). Here's an example:

```
<span>Message: {{ msg }}</span>
```

In the above code, `msg` is a variable that should be declared in the `<script>` section of your Vue component.

To dynamically change the URL path, we'll combine interpolation with JavaScript. Here's an example of how you can achieve it:

```
<a :href="`/profile/${userId}/edit`" />
```

In the above code, `userId` is a variable that you should declare in the `<script>` section. The `:href` attribute with the `:` prefix is Vue's shorthand for binding a property.

Alternatively, you can use a computed property in the `<script>` section to hold the complete URL:

```
computed: {
  url() {
    return `/profile/${userId}/edit`;
  }
}
```

Then, in your template, you can use the `url` computed property like this:

```
<a :href="url" />
```

By doing this, Vue will dynamically update the URL based on the value of the `userId` variable, allowing you to generate the desired URL path for your anchor tag button.